# How to visually distinguish metal film and ceramic capacitors (leaded)?

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor, ceramic, metal-film

This question only involves the leaded components.

Electrolytic capacitors are each to recognize since they are usually in cylindrical cans. However, I am not sure about distinguishing the other two types, metal film vs. ceramic, if I come across a device others designed.

Comment: What research have you done so far how to distinguish between them? Have you for example googled for images of ceramic and metal film capacitors?

Comment: They don't look like each other.

Comment: If you relax the *visually* requirement, film capacitors don't exhibit significant voltage dependence--so if you measure the capacitance with a DC bias of nearly the rated voltage, a film capacitor will have about the same as its rated capacitance, while a ceramic capacitor, if it's a high-κ one (anything bigger than a nF will almost definitely be), it will have probably less than half its rated capacitance. Though if the ceramic cap has a C0G or U2J dielectric, it will look the same as a film cap to this test.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering per se, but adding an image to illustrate they can sometimes be ambiguous:

[image: Capacitor lineup]

Left: marking on top is "22K400∎".  22nF 10% 400V.  Appears to be polypropylene (nice high Q factor).  Unknown manufacture (salvaged).  For reference, it's about 11 x 10 mm, 3.4mm thick.

Center: new (from a couple years ago) TDK FG22X7R1H225KNT06, a 2.2uF 50V 10% X7R ceramic.  Basically an MLCC with leads welded on, dipped in epoxy.  This is the smallest one here.

Right: 2.4nF 5% 100VDC polypropylene, possibly by TSC Group.  Salvaged.  Also pretty thin, but a noticeable bulge implying a wound rather than stacked or chip construction.

Most parts you will see in repair will be more obvious.

But this isn't a very design oriented question so I'll leave things at this.